# |error: 'true' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'free'?|

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to [build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXD3s.png) a guessing game.

Hi, I'm trying to build a guessing game in C. But when I pass `true` in while loop in throws the following error:

```
error: 'true' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'free'?
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWshh.png)

How can I solve this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
   {
    srand(time(0));
    int hidden = rand()%100 +1;
    printf("%d\n", hidden);

    while (true){
        int guess;
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        if(guess == hidden){
            printf("You are right");
            break;
        }
        else if(guess > hidden){
            printf("Guess smaller");
        }
        else{
            printf("Guess Larger");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `true` and `false` are defined in `<stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 1):

[`true`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) is declared in `stdbool.h`.

You could also use `1` instead of `true`.